# Installing .sh file - mojo problem

Tags: installation, 13.04, .sh

So guys, I've done a lot of research on how to install and `.sh` file, and I tried it all but none of it works.

Here is what I get after every possible way I've tried to run it:

```
Uncompressing Mojo Setup..............
Collecting info for this system...
Operating system: linux
CPU Arch: x86_64
trying mojosetup in bin/linux/x86_64

PANIC
Initial setup failed. Cannot continue.

Error: Couldn't run mojosetup
```

I've tried to Google it but I found nothing so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the .sh file?

Comment: Or say what setup it is. Somebody else might be able to test it if they also have it.

Comment: how to post contents of the .sh file? 

hmhm, its a torrent .sh of game amnesia

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem while installing [Amensia AMFP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amnesia:_A_Machine_for_Pigs). The solution was to unpack it with:

```
unzip ./AmneiaAMFP-1.0.0.sh
```

Explaintion: The `.sh` file has zip-file packed at the [end of the file](http://www.frictionalgames.com/forum/thread-23199.html), which you need to unpack before usage.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case, I could install successfully after deleting all spaces in the name of the folder the setup file was lying in.